# How to cross reference based on foreign keys? Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter, django-views

I have a Django app where a traveller 'requests' a local to take him out on an excursion. After they have gone out, they leave a reference for each other to mention whether they had fun and some written description.

On the homepage I want to automatically feature the last two requests where both the traveller and the local have already met AND left a reference for each other.

Currently data comes from population script.

This is the Request model:

```
 class Request(models.Model):
    """traveler requests local to take her out upon liking her profile"""
    traveler = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='traveler_requests')
    local = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='local_requested')
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField()#date of excursion
    local_approval = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

This is the Reference model:

```
class Reference(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='referencer')#can be local or traveler
    referenced = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='referencee')#can be local or traveler
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="default reference")
    fun = models.BooleanField() #did you have fun with the person or not?
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())#in order to pull the last ref on index page
    local = models.BooleanField(default=True) #Is the author a local ?
```

This is my attempt at achieving what what I want:

```
reqs = Request.objects.filter(local_approval=True).order_by('-date')[:2]

for i in range(len(reqs)):
    local_references_traveler = Reference.objects.filter(fun=True, author=reqs[i].local, referenced=reqs[i].traveler, local=True).latest()
    traveler_references_local = Reference.objects.filter(fun=True, author=reqs[i].traveler, referenced=reqs[i].local, local=False).latest()
```

However this brings back the last two requests in general (by date), I want to return the last two requests where the both people have left a reference for each other and pull these references.

The only way this seem to work is if I populate a big amount of references in the population script making the app look bad.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must refactor your model, the best aproach is make "Reference" one_to_one relationship with "Request", like this:

```
class Reference(models.Model):
    request = models.OneToOneField(
        Request,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    author_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    referenced_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    author_fun = models.BooleanField()
    referenced_fun = models.BooleanField()
    author_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    referenced_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Then you can try this:

```
r = Reference.objects.select_related('request').filter(author_fun=True,referenced_fun=True).order_by('-request__date')
# Don´t forget index or another filter for optimization
```

or you can make a simple FK to Request, like this:

```
class Reference(model.Models):
    request= ForeignKey(Request)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='referencer')#can be local or traveler
    # referenced = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='referencee')#this isn't necesary
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="default reference")
    fun = models.BooleanField() #did you have fun with the person or not?
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now())#in order to pull the last ref on index page
    local = models.BooleanField(default=True) #Is the author a local ?
```

Then you can make a annotate clause:

```
ref_group = Reference.objects.values('request__id') \
    .annotate(num_reference=Count('id')) \
    .filter(num_reference=2)
    .order_by('-request__id')
```

... with this, you can get all the "request.id" with both references.